# Взаимодействие клавиатур

Tags: python, aiogram

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему пишу бота на aiogram. Сама суть такова. Есть меню настроек, где можно выбрать из представленного списка валюту (скрин прикреплю ниже). При нажатии любой из кнопок, значение выбранной валюты должна передаваться в обычную кнопку меню. Если можно то с примерами, буду благодарен, либо подскажите в каком направлении двигаться.. В конечном итоге должно получится BTC/RUB, BTC/KZT и т.п.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код хендлера:

```
@dp.message_handler(Command(commands=['set']))
async def setting_menu(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("⚙ Настройки", reply_markup=staye)
    await message.answer(f"{message.from_user.first_name}, вы находитесь в настройках.\n\n"
                         f"Выберите интересующую валюту в меню ниже.\n"
                         f"Выбор валюты влияет на отображение списков спроса и предложений.",
                         reply_markup=set_menu)
```

Код инлайн клавиатуры:

```
set_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1,
                                inline_keyboard=[
                                    [
                                        InlineKeyboardButton(
                                            text="RUB",
                                            callback_data='1'
                                        ),
                                        InlineKeyboardButton(
                                            text="UAH",
                                            callback_data='2'
                                        ),
                                        InlineKeyboardButton(
                                            text="USD",
                                            callback_data='3'
                                        ),
                                        InlineKeyboardButton(
                                            text="KZT",
                                            callback_data='4'
                                        ),
                                        InlineKeyboardButton(
                                            text="BYN",
                                            callback_data='5'
                                        ),
                                    ]
                                ])
```

Код обычной клавиатуры:

```
staye = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2, resize_keyboard=True)
course = KeyboardButton(text="BTC/....")
course1 = KeyboardButton(text="test1")
course2 = KeyboardButton(text="test2")
staye.add(course, course1, course2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать, только в том случае если после нажатия пользователя, к примеру на кнопку UAH на инлайн клавиатуре, вы будете редактировать свою обычную клавиатуру для пользователя и отправлять ему новое сообщение с отредактированной клавиатурой, но вы должны понимать какую кнопку на клавиатуре хотите отредактировать и затем только редактировать её Текст.

> Однако если вы не совсем поняли, вам обязательно придется отправлять новое сообщение с этой ( новой ) клавиатурой, либо вы могли бы изменить прошлое сообщение ( но вам это сделать невозможно - так как прошлое сообщение с инлайн клавиатурой, а не обычной клавиатурой ), если попытаетесь - сможете увидеть эту ошибку:

```
raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.InlineKeyboardExpected: Inline keyboard expected
```

> Итог ( честно говоря эти два варианта хороши, какой лучше для вас я даже не знаю.. ) :

1. Отправлять новое сообщение с новой клавиатурой
2. Редактировать инлайн клавиатуру, не используя при этом вовсе обычную клавиатуру

Answer (score 0):

Никак, при нажатии на обычную кнопку она обрабатывается как текстовое сообщение, и обработчик для неё должен быть как для обычной текстовой команды.

Inline-кнопки в этом плане лучше, так как они более удобны для работы, можно сделать динамический обработчик, например.

А мешать два типа друг с другом это и с точки зрения юзабилити не очень, а уж тем более реализовать взаимодействие двух клавиатур друг с другом без костылей невозможно.

Определитесь, какую клавиатуру Вы хотите видеть в боте, и исходя из этого можно будет помочь с Вашим кодом, написать соответствующий обработчик.